# git cherrypick changes to release branch

Tags: git, github

I have commit A, commit B and C that got merged into branch A. C obviously has A and B as well. I have a local fork of branch A that I've been pushing changes to.

I also have a fork of branch B (release branch). I need to push changes from branch A/branchA_fork into branch B. What's the best way to do this? Everyone in my team suggests I cherry pick manually. Sounds very error prone. Would love some tips on a clean way to do this.

Comment: _"Sounds very error prone"_ - what makes you think this?

Comment: I would prefer not having to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you can [cherry-pick a *range* of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309), you could `git cherry-pick A..C` in one go.

That is the equivalent of:

```
        af--af--af (branchA_fork)
       /
a--a--A            (branchA)

b--b--b            (branchB)
```

```bash
git switch branch A/branchA_fork 
git rebase --onto branchB $(git merge-base branchA branchA_fork) branchA_fork
```

That would replay any commit after the `branchA_fork` origin commit from `branchA` (commit `A`), up to `branchA_fork` head onto `branchB`.